# mongoDB data filter by range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one collection where I want to filter data based on a range.
Range will go like this:
Last week (last_week)
Last month (last_month)
Last quarter (last_quarter)

I want to take input as last_week or last_month or last_quarter and based upon the input given, I want to filter data from documents matching the criteria supplied.

Is it possible to build a criteria on the fly based upon the input given?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Build your criteria like this,

```
query = {};
query.createdDate = {
    $gt: last_week,
    $lt: last_month,
};
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to do that in aggregation block. Explaining example more here:
Input field will be either last_week or last_month not both.

aggregation should first translate last_week or last_month to a date range on one date field.